# how to add javascript inside php file with html content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin. inside this plugin there is a php file.(for example name.php) this php file contains some codes which they are inside this code:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-dokan-single-variations">
//codes
</script>
```

Now I want to add some Javascript codes and I've tried this code:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-dokan-single-variations">
<script type="text/javascript">
//mycodes
</script> 
//codes
</script>
```

Also I've tried echo script but it doesn't work either.
Please tell me how can I add some javascript code inside this file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to include the raw string `</script>` inside a script element.

You would need to find some alternative representation of it (such as `<!-- TEMPLATE: SCRIPT END TAG -->` and then modify the code (which is presumably JavaScript) that reads the value of the `<script type="text/html">` element so it can replace that alternative representation with the end tag you actually want.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know what your php file looks like but you can echo your script like this

```
<?php 

    echo '
    <script>

    // your code here

    </script> 
    ';

?>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how you output the code from the PHP. The HTML will still be wrong when it gets to the client.